# How do I change the x-axis precision with morris.js?

Tags: graph, morris.js

I have a graph that plots dates along the x-axis and hours slept on the y-axis.

If I display 7 days of data the x-axis displays each date and graph looks good:

[image]

When I toss 8 weeks worth of data into the graph, morris.js auto-adjusts the precision of the x-axis **labels** to show fewer dates (great!) but doesn't do the same adjustment for the plot points, so the graph looks like this:

[image]

**How do I make it so morris.js only places plot points at each label interval?**

Here's the code that displays the graph:

```
$ ->
  new Morris.Line(
    element: 'naps_chart',
    data: $('#naps_chart').data('naps'),
    xkey: 'happened_at',
    ykeys: ['time'],
    labels: ['Hours']
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest/best solution I found to this problem is to set `pointSize: 0` and just smooth the graph.  It still shows the plot points on hover and looks much better.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try with this setting

```
xLabelAngle: 45,
```

Then you can see your graph as like follow image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am a novice in this area myself, so please forgive me if you've already considered and taken this into account: does the time specification need more precision or descriptive formatting for 'Morris' to understand it?
For instance (from this Website, which I've found useful in this area: http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html):

-- parseTime            Set to false to skip time/date parsing for X values, instead treating them as an equally-spaced series.

-- yLabelFormat     A function that accepts y-values and formats them for display as y-axis labels. 
eg: function (y) { return y.toString() + 'km'; }

The site should offer more 'insight' (please excuse the pun) and it may simply be that another or slightly different operation or command is needed to execute the proper segmenting of your x-axis equation's value.

Hope this helps, even a little.

~

Answer (score 0):

xLabelMargin: 10,

Try this in

```
 Morris.Bar({
//
xLabelMargin: 10,

//

});
```